# JavaScript fetch is sending same request twice

Tags: javascript, html, go

I'm trying to post a query to an endpoint using the following JavaScript function:

```
function purchaseDomain() {
        console.log("purchase domain")
        let formData = new FormData();
        let domain = document.getElementById("domain").value;
        let provider = document.getElementById("provider").value;
        formData.append("domain", domain);
        formData.append("provider", provider);

        let response = fetch("/app/domains/purchase", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {console.log(data)})
      }
```

This function is called from the following:

```
        <div class="text-center">
            <a onclick="purchaseDomain()" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Purchase</a>
        </div>
```

The function pulls the parameters from this section on the page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-2 grid-margin stretch-card">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Domain Name</label>
      <div class="overflow-auto mt-1" style="max-height: 100px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domain" id="domain" placeholder="Enter a domain name to lookup">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Provider</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="provider" name="provider" value="">
        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
        {{range _, name := providers}}
        {{if name == "namecheap"}}<option value="{{name}}">Namecheap</option>{{end}}
        {{if name == "godaddy"}}<option value="{{name}}">Godaddy</option>{{end}}
        {{end}}
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <a onclick="getDomainInfo()" value="Lookup" class="btn btn-success mt-3 mb-2">Lookup</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 grid-margin stretch-card">
    <div id="lookup-status" class="ml-4">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm using a Go backend to handle the request, the function looks like this:

```
func (m *Repository) DomainsPurchase(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(0)
    if err != nil {
        printTemplateError(w, err)
    }

    formDomain := r.PostForm.Get("domain")
    formProvider := r.PostForm.Get("provider")


    if formProvider == "godaddy" {
        err := domains.Repo.GoDaddyPurchaseDomain(formDomain)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/text")
    w.Write([]byte("done"))

}
```

This all works fine, the problem is that once the first request has completed, it sends a second identical request, this doesn't get logged in my browser network monitor, but the request logged in my browser looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarycTlcVzGUZXx7rQRD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="domain"

testingdomaif4fan.com
------WebKitFormBoundarycTlcVzGUZXx7rQRD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="provider"

godaddy
------WebKitFormBoundarycTlcVzGUZXx7rQRD--
```

The headers for the request/response look like this:

```
General:
 Request URL: http://localhost:8000/app/domains/purchase
 Request Method: POST
 Status Code: 200 OK
 Remote Address: [::1]:8000
 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response:
 Content-Length: 143
 Content-Type: application/text
 Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2022 19:34:08 GMT
 Vary: Cookie
 Accept: */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 260
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data
 Cookie: cookies_here

Request:
 Host: localhost:8000
 Origin: http://localhost:8000
 Referer: http://localhost:8000/app/domains/add
 Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
 Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
 Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
 Sec-GPC: 1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
 Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

However, if I add a print statement in the route handler, I can see the function gets called twice, and it executes the GoDaddyPurchaseDomain function twice too. Why is this happening?

I can see the response in my browser console:

```
add:403 purchase domain
20:26:31.836 add:410 Fetch finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/app/domains/purchase".
  purchaseDomain @ add:410
  onclick @ add:1
20:26:31.836 add:415 done
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the DomainPurchase route is setup here:

```
func routes() http.Handler {
    // configure chi router to handle requests
    mux := chi.NewRouter()

    mux.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    // mux.Use(NoSurf)
    mux.Use(SessionLoad)
    mux.Post("/app/domains/purchase", handlers.Repo.DomainsPurchase)
    return mux
}
```

Comment: how are you routing to the `DomainsPurchase(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`request ?

Comment: That's not two requests. It's a single multipart/form-data request with two parts named domain and provider. This matches the JS code.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the routes, thanks.

Comment: @Peter that is just the request taken from the browser log, it's the actual Go function that runs twice. For example if I print the domain and provider variables taken from that multipart form, they both print out on two separate occasions and the GoDaddyPurchaseDomain function is run twice.

Comment: Is the browser perhaps sending a pre-flight request before the `POST` request? In the Network tab, is there a request to your endpoint using the `OPTION` verb before the `POST`? As an aside, it'd be a good idea to use a `button` instead of an anchor here - anchors are specifically for links - buttons are for general non-navigation-related interaction. Attaching an event listener to the button (`submitButton.addEventListener('click', purchaseDomain)` ) instead of using `onclick` encapsulates the entire interaction in your JS, too